# Why does Visual Studio install onto multiple drives?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, installation

I'm installing Visual Studio 2008 onto a new machine (yeah yeah, old-fashioned I know but I want to do it) and the installer seems determined to write data to *TWO* of the three hard drives attached to my system.  No matter what options I choose, it always tells me that some drive space is needed on C (my main drive) and X (my backup drive).  I only want stuff written to C.  Here's an illustration:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 setup]

It always requires some space on my X volume.  Why?  Is there any way to force it to install to just C?  I guess I could physically disconnect all drives other than C, but does anyone know why VS2008 is so determined to write to more than one drive?

Comment: what's on your X: drive? If you've relocated any standard windows folders there (e.g. my documents, program files, etc...), that'd explain it. plenty of apps still insist on dumping their junk into %WINDIR% on top of whatever other locations you're telling it to install to.

Comment: It just uses the other drive to store temporarily. At the end of installation you will not find anything releted to VS their, installer deletes all the temp folder it created and even if it didn't do that, you can delete those files.

Comment: I'd guess at the TEMP folder as well.  It leaves the installer log files there (dd*.txt), they are big.

Comment: @MarcB Gah, you're right; there is some stuff on X I didn't expect.  The likeliest candidate is an MSOCache directory.  So my question becomes, how do I stop windows writing cache stuff to anything but my C drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer was the Visual Studio 2008 installer wanted to put its MSOCache directory on my X drive.  The installer seemed wedded to the idea of not using my C drive for this directory; even when I disconnected my X drive, it then started saying it wanted to use some space on my Z drive instead!!!

In the end, I forced it to use my C drive for everything by disconnecting all drives except the C drive during the Visual Studio 2008 installation.

Comment: Man, that's obnoxious behavior.

Comment: I believe that the algorithm is something like "Put temporary files on the drive with the most free space".  Which is not very helpful when that drive is especially slow... Often you'd want to use a ramdrive for temp files, but those are pretty limited size-wise.